# Specify local path to virtual env in Rproject which is on git

Tags: python, r, git, rstudio, python-venv

I'm checking out an R project from a repository which uses some python scripts as well. The repo recommends installing a virtual environment with all packages which I did.

Now in Rstudio, I can specify the path to the interpreter from the venv I created and it works, however `the_project.Rproj` is on source control (and I believe rightfully so) but that's where my python interpreter is now specified.

Where should I specify the python interpreter in an R project which is on source control?